# How to save specific file .docx with seeder in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to save file .docx in mysql database in laravel with seeder,,

this is my code in DocumentTableSeeder

```
 public function run()
{
    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/SOW.docx'),

    ]);

    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/RFQ.docx'),

    ]);

    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/TKDN.docx'),

    ]);

}
```

column **filename** in document table is **string**, but i got error like this
[image]

how to save .docx file in mysql database with seeder laravel ?
plis help
Thanks

Comment: why not you just upload the file on server and keep the path store in database? Is there any specific requirement to store the file content in database?

Comment: store only file name in database column and store file path in public folder you can access file from public folder

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column type to `longText`, maybe the file's content is truncated.

And use `htmlenties` function to convert file content to the safe content.

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => htmlentities(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/SOW.docx')),
    ]);

    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => htmlentities(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/RFQ.docx')),
    ]);

    DB::table('document')->insert([
        'filename' => htmlentities(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/seeds/TKDN.docx')),
    ]);
}
```

I don't know about your logic but you shouldn't save file content into the database, you should save file path instead of file content.

Comment: how to save file content into database ? give me one example

Comment: Did you change column type from `string` to `longText` and test again. I think it should work for you.

Comment: i already change type from string to longtext, but still error like above

Comment: @Bian I've just updated my answer. I've tested it and it should works for you now.

Comment: @Bian How is it now? :)